# In Firebase, how do I handle new children added after I statically loaded the latest N?

Tags: dart, firebase

Here's my pagination/infinite scrolling scenario:

1. Load the initial N with `startAt().limit(N).once('value')`. Populate a list `items`.
2. On scroll, load the next N. (I pass a priority to `startAt()` but that's tangential.)
3. When a new item is added, I'd like to pop it to the top of `items`.

If I use a `.onChildAdded` listener for step 3, it finds all the items including those I've already pulled in thus creating duplicates. Is there a better way?

Another method would be to use the `.onChildAdded` listener for the initial N in step 1 instead of `.once`, but when the initial N items come in I do `items.add(item)` to sort one after the other as they are already in order, but with the new one that comes in after the fact I need to somehow know it's unique so I can do `items.insert(0, item)` to force it to the top of the list. I'm not sure how to set this up, or if I'm off the mark here.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Still in flux, see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/GyYF7hfmlEM

Here's a working solution I came up with:

```dart
class FeedViewModel extends Observable {
  int pageSize = 20;
  @observable bool reloadingContent = false;
  @observable bool reachedEnd = false;
  var snapshotPriority = null;
  bool isFirstRun = true;

  FeedViewModel(this.app) {
    loadItemsByPage();
  }

  /**
   * Load more items pageSize at a time.
   */
  loadItemsByPage() {
    reloadingContent = true;

    var itemsRef = f.child('/items_by_community/' + app.community.alias)
      .startAt(priority: (snapshotPriority == null) ? null : snapshotPriority).limit(pageSize+1);
    int count = 0;

    // Get the list of items, and listen for new ones.
    itemsRef.once('value').then((snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach((itemSnapshot) {
        count++;
        // Don't process the extra item we tacked onto pageSize in the limit() above.
        print("count: $count, pageSize: $pageSize");

        // Track the snapshot's priority so we can paginate from the last one.
        snapshotPriority = itemSnapshot.getPriority();

        if (count > pageSize) return;

        // Insert each new item into the list.
        // TODO: This seems weird. I do it so I can separate out the method for adding to the list.
        items.add(toObservable(processItem(itemSnapshot)));

        // If this is the first item loaded, start listening for new items.
        // By using the item's priority, we can listen only to newer items.
        if (isFirstRun == true) {
          listenForNewItems(snapshotPriority);
          isFirstRun = false;
        }
      });

      // If we received less than we tried to load, we've reached the end.
      if (count <= pageSize) reachedEnd = true;
      reloadingContent = false;
    });

    // When an item changes, let's update it.
    // TODO: Does pagination mean we have multiple listeners for each page? Revisit.
    itemsRef.onChildChanged.listen((e) {
      Map currentData = items.firstWhere((i) => i['id'] == e.snapshot.name);
      Map newData = e.snapshot.val();

      newData.forEach((k, v) {
        if (k == "createdDate" || k == "updatedDate") v = DateTime.parse(v);
        if (k == "star_count") v = (v != null) ? v : 0;
        if (k == "like_count") v = (v != null) ? v : 0;

        currentData[k] = v;
      });
    });
  }

  listenForNewItems(endAtPriority) {
    // If this is the first item loaded, start listening for new items.
    var itemsRef = f.child('/items').endAt(priority: endAtPriority);
    itemsRef.onChildAdded.listen((e) {
      print(e.snapshot.getPriority());
      print(endAtPriority);
      if (e.snapshot.getPriority() != endAtPriority) {
        print(e.snapshot.val());
        // Insert new items at the top of the list.
        items.insert(0, toObservable(processItem(e.snapshot)));
      }
    });
  }

  void paginate() {
    if (reloadingContent == false && reachedEnd == false) loadItemsByPage();
  }
}
```

1. Load the initial N with `startAt().limit(N).once('value')`. Populate a list `items`.
2. On the first run, note the first item's priority, then start an `onChildAdded` listener that has an `endAt()` with that priority. This means it'll only listen to stuff from there and above.
3. In that listener, ignore the first event which is the topmost item we already have, and for everything else, add that to the top of the list.
4. Of course, on scroll, load the next N.

EDIT: Updated w/ some fixes, and including the listener for changes.